# how to get the ip address of Wazuh manager OVA file in vmware workstation

Tags: ip-address, wazuh

I have used the Wazuh OVA file in VirtualBox without any problem. But when I launch the Wazuh OVA file in VMware Workstation and try to know the IP address by typing `ip addr` I get this ---

[image]

Can anyone help me understand where or what the IP address of my Wazuh manager is?

and what does `00:0c:29:7e:c1:16` mean?

I tried ifconfig --- no result found
I tried ipconfig --- Definity no result to be found
Then I used the ip addr and you already see what I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the IP address of your server with the following command:

```
ip a
```

[image]

Then, identify your network adapter (note that you configure this adapter in your VM's network settings).

[image]

Depending on the network configuration you have set up on the VM, you will have different IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the DHCP server for an IP address by running the following command:

```
dhclient
```

[image: Get IP address in OVA]